# Running a loop on every split

Tags: python, string, loops, split

I am answering questions on codebattle however I am stuck trying to complete a loop. The question is move the first letter of each word to the end of it, then add "ay" to the end of the word. Leave punctuation marks untouched. Ex. pig_it('Pig latin is cool') = igPay atinlay siay oolcay. my basic solution was to split all words and run a loop on them that would perform the action on every word. However it only runs on the first split.

```
def pig_it(text):
    splits = text.split()
    for split in splits:
        ans = split[1::] + split[0] + "ay"
        return ans
```

Comment: You have a `return` inside the loop, which exits the function immediately.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to declare `ans` outside the loop and keep appending to it. If you just call it inside the loop it will be replaced with a new value each time and you will get only one word.
2. The `return` statement should not be part of the `for` loop. If you indent it properly, such that it is outside the loop, you should get the desired output.

```
def pig_it(text):
    splits = text.split()
    ans=[]
    for split in splits:
        ans.append(split[1::] + split[0] + "ay")
    return " ".join(ans)
```

Comment: This will only return one word.

Comment: @JohnGordon, yes my bad. I've edited the answer and have added an explanation for it.

Comment: Yah this is what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Koedeen, can you mark it as the answer then please.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
def piglatin(s):
  new = []
  s = s.split(' ')
  for i in s:
    main = list(i)
    move = main[0]
    main.remove(move)
    main.append(move + 'ay')
    new.append(''.join(main))
  print(' '.join(new))
```

Comment: this is what i needed